# Modify a document inside an array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Past answers (from mid 2013 and before) don't seem to work and links to the documentation are all out of date.

Example user object:

```js
{
    "name": "Joe Bloggs",
    "email": "joebloggs@example.com",
    "workstations" : [
                         { "number" : "10001",
                           "nickname" : "home" },
                         { "number" : "10002",
                           "nickname" : "work" },
                         { "number" : "10003",
                           "nickname" : "vacation" }
                     ]
}
```

How can I modify the nickname of a workstation?

I tried using `$set`, `workstations.$` and `workstations.nickname` but none gave the desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, you have to use array index. For example, you want to update the nickname of `10002`: `{$set:{"workstations.1.nickname":"newnickname"}}`

Here is the complete example:

```
> db.test.update({"_id" : ObjectId("5332b7cf4761549fb7e1e72f")},{$set:{"workstations.1.nickname":"newnickname"}})
> db.test.findOne()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5332b7cf4761549fb7e1e72f"),
        "email" : "joebloggs@example.com",
        "name" : "Joe Bloggs",
        "workstations" : [
                {
                        "number" : "10001",
                        "nickname" : "home"
                },
                {
                        "nickname" : "newnickname",
                        "number" : "10002"
                },
                {
                        "number" : "10003",
                        "nickname" : "vacation"
                }
        ]
}
>
```

If you don't know the index (position of the workstations), you can update the doc using `$elemMatch`:

```
>db.test.update(
    { 
        "email": "joebloggs@example.com",
        "workstations": { "$elemMatch" { "number" : "10002" } }
    },
    {
        "$set": { "workstations.$.nickname": "newnickname2" }
    }
)
>
```

Comment: Thanks will mark as answer, is there any way of getting the array index using the workstation number?

Answer (score 1):

@naimdjon's answer would work.  To generalize, you could use the [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator in combination with the [`$ positional`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator to update **one element** in the array using below query:

```js
db.test.update({
    // Find the document where name="Joe Bloggs" and the element in the workstations array where number = "10002"
    "name": "Joe Bloggs", 
    "workstations":{$elemMatch:{"number":"10002"}}
},
{
    // Update the nickname in the element matched 
    $set:{"workstations.$.nickname":"newnickname"}
})
```

**Note:** $elemMatch is only required if you need to match more than one component in the array.  If you are going to match on just the `number`, you could use `"workstations.number":"10002"`

Answer (score 1):

As long as you know "which" entry you wish to update then the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator can be of help. But you need to update your query form:

```js
db.collection.update(
    { 
        "email": "joebloggs@example.com",
        "workstations": { "$elemMatch" { "nickname" : "work" } }
    },
    {
        "$set": { "workstations.$.nickname": "new name" }
    }
)
```

So that is the general form. What you **need** to do here is "match" something in the array in order to get a "position" to use for the update.

Alternately, where you **know** the position, then you can just "specify" the position with "dot notation":

```js
db.collection.update(
    { 
        "email": "joebloggs@example.com",
    },
    {
        "$set": { "workstations.1.nickname": "new name" }
    }
)
```

Which updates the **second** element in the array, and does not need the "matching" part in the query.